# Using RelBuilder how to create SELECT and WHEREclause?

Tags: apache-calcite

I have the following code where I am trying to create a relational algebra: 
final RelNode relNode = relBuilder.scan(index).build();

I am looking for a sample code where I can create a SELECE and WHERE clause in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/algebra.html)? There are several examples there.

> ```
> final RelNode node = builder
>   .scan("EMP")
>   .aggregate(builder.groupKey("DEPTNO"),
>       builder.count(false, "C"),
>       builder.sum(false, "S", builder.field("SAL")))
>   .filter(
>       builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.GREATER_THAN,
>           builder.field("C"),
>           builder.literal(10)))
>   .build();
> System.out.println(RelOptUtil.toString(node));
> ```
>
> is equivalent to SQL
>
> ```
> SELECT deptno, count(*) AS c, sum(sal) AS s
> FROM emp
> GROUP BY deptno
> HAVING count(*) > 10
> ```